# Accessing an endpoint in hapi-swagger

Tags: javascript, node.js, swagger, authorization, swagger-ui

I have hapi-swagger package installed and configured to use in my node.js server using hapi.js.

I am trying to access `/documentation` and `/swagger.json` endpoint on my port `9000` on my `localhost`. I am trying to access it with `GET` request but I am getting `401` (`Unauthorized`) error. Mainly I need to access `/swagger.json`

If I access the the endpoint through UI. It alerts me for authentication. I need to input username and password. But I am unable to bypass that or authenticate myself while sending the request.
I tried sending *Authorization* - `Bearer ${token}`, *username* and *password* in headers but still got the `401` error.

I need help to access the endpoints. What is happening and what is that I am missing in this scenario?

I was trying to fetch `/swagger.json` endpoint on my `localhost` on `9000` port with a `GET` request. I was expecting to get the json in the response

```
const axios = require('axios');

try {
 const URL = 'http://localhost:9000/swagger.json';
 const response = await axios.get(URL);
 console.log(response);
} catch (error) {
 console.error('Error fetching Swagger JSON:', error.message);
}
```

The `swagger.json` provides all the basic information about my server and APIs those are in the server. And I am unable to access that file because of `401` error. I also tried logging in UI and then accessing with `GET` request. But the result remained same. `401` error.